# HTML parsing: how to get link tag from remote site

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, xcode, parsing

I have a site (for example [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/)) which contain link tag, for example

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss" />
```

So how I can get title "RSS" and href from it?

**Update 1:**
I've tried to convert site into string using

```
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com/"]] returningResponse:NULL error:NULL];
NSString *HTMLWithFeeds = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But I dont know what to do now...

**Update 2:**

It is not clear from my post, but in addition in should find at this site link with type="application/rss+xml"

Comment: Is this a string? Are you already using an XML parser? More information, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might try using regular expressions

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"<link.*?href="(.*?)".*?>"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
     NSRange matchRange = [match range];
     NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
     NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
}
```

Apples documentation has some examples about how to further use and access the matches:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

e.g. something like the following regex should do for the hrefs:

```
<link.*?href="(.*?)".*?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using jquery,
$("link").attr("title"） --> print "RSS"
$("link").attr("href") --> print http://*****

if you want to get the href content, using jquery ajax.
$.get("http://***", function(result){});

Answer (score 0):

Create an `NSXMLDocument` using `-initWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` with the `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML` option.  Then, you can navigate the hierarchy of nodes starting with `-rootElement`.  Or, you can use XPath, like `[doc nodesForXPath:@"//link@title"]`.